# Does `int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};` set aside two chunks of memories?

Tags: c

I am learning array and desire to explore its details with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};

int main(void)
{
    printf("The address of arr is %p, the second element is %d", arr, *(arr+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Run it and get

```
$ ./a.out
The address of arr is 0x102471018, the second element is 2
```

Does `arr[3] = {1, 2, 3} implement two jobs:
1. set aside a chunk of memory to store {1, 2, 3};
2. set another chunk of memory to store address of it as a pointer named arr?

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: No. Arrays are *not* pointers. They can however *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: It's not easy to understand `decay`,  decay the pointer arr? could you please elaborate it in answer?  @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: An array is an array. But when used in a context when a pointer is expected, it will *decay* to a pointer to its first element, e.g. `&arr[0]`.

Comment: I got it, its same as *"string", could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: compiler decay array to it 0 index address and assign it to variable void.